# Identifying the list of "actions" (which properties will be assigned) in an Action<T> class

Tags: c#, delegates

English is not my native language, i hope i will make my question clear enough.

I'd like to know how to identify wich actions are contained in an Action class (precisely, wich properties will be called) when executed.

Imagine a simple Employee class...

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

...and a simple Update() method taking an Action<> as a parameter

```
public static void Update(Action<Employee> action) {
    //HERE : how could i know which properties will be assigned by analyzing the Action<Employee> object ?

    Employee em = new Employee();

    action(em);

    //Only FirstName and LastName have been assigned to "em"
}
```

The Update method can be called this way :

```
//Call the Update method with only two "actions" : assign FirstName and LastName properties.
Update(e => { e.FirstName = "firstname"; e.LastName = "lastname"; });
```

**My problem is to identify, inside the Update() method, which properties have been "planned" for assignment (and the associated values) inside the Action<> object.**

**How could i discover, by analyzing the Action<> object, that only the properties FirstName and LastName will be assigned with the values "firstname" and "lastname" ? Is it possible at all ?**

I cannot find any help on google and SO on this. Maybe i'm asking the question the wrong way.

At the end of the message is the entire program that can be executed/debugged.

Thanks in advance to everybody here on SO.

Mike

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestAction
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Employee
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Call the Update method with only two "actions" : assign FirstName and LastName properties.
            Update(e => { e.FirstName = "firstname"; e.LastName = "lastname"; });
        }

        public static void Update(Action<Employee> action)
        {
            //HERE : how could i know which properties will be assigned by analyzing the Action<Employee> object ?

            Employee em = new Employee();

            action(em);

            //Only FirstName and LastName have been assigned to "em"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the properties are changed since what ?

Comment: Look into expression trees.

Comment: Does `Employee` implement some interface that contains the properties?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth : No it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

This is not an easy problem to tackle, but let me outline the ways *I* know how to do this, if you really need to do it this way.

**Disassemble and interpret**

This would involve getting a .NET (or x86/x64) disassembler, which you would run at runtime, pointing it at the method in question, and then analyzing the output, looking for access to fields on the target type.

I would say this is difficult, and you would need a very good understanding of MSIL and possibly optimization techniques employed by the compiler in order to get what you want from this technique.

**Use proxy object which records access**

You could create a proxy object which you would pass to the action delegate. This proxy object would record, probably in a boolean variable per property, that each property was accessed. You would then look at those boolean values afterwards to determine which properties was accessed.

This is much easier to do, you would need to make your class virtual, and each property also virtual, and then create a descendant class, which you can do using Reflection.Emit or other ways to create types at runtime.

*However*, it requires you to actually execute all the code in the method targeted by the action delegate, which may be unwanted.

You could also use a regular copy of the original object, give each property some magic value that you know won't be given to it by the action delegate, call the delegate, and check for differences between the magic values and the current values (after the call). This, unfortunately, also requires you to call the delegate, and will also execute any property setters on the target object, both of which may be unwanted.

**My opinion**

In my opinion, you would be much better off finding a different way to do this, which is more explicit.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I already thought about dynamic proxies implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, but i cannot make the properties virtual on the intended class. Using a .Net disassembler is way too complex i think... What did you mean by "or use reflection to look" ? Did you mean use reflection on the Action class ?

Comment: I have no idea what I meant by that, I removed it now. You're right that the two ways I outline is no good, and that's the problem, there is no good way to do this without help from the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can see what was changed in some built-in way, as what was changed is regard of the *current* state of your instance. 
Example:

```
A {Name="Patrick"} //init 
A {Name = "Jane"} // changed from Patrick to Jane
A {Name = "Martin"} //changed from Jane to Martin
```

So there is no other known to me way, that manage this by yourself. 
Keep track of all property setters, and when one of them was `set` by caller, put in some local to instance of object list the name of the property changed.

On `Update` call, scroll over the list of names of the properties changed, get only their value and update them (all via reflection). After, on successful update, cleanup the list.

Just an idea, but there could be other ways to achieve this too.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everybody for making me realize that delegates cannot be analyzed (without your explanations i still would have been trying to figure out how...).

To achieve what i was trying to do, i needed the possibility to pass a list of property assignments, and the possibility to analyze that list. I came to the conclusion, with your help, that only Expression Trees could be analyzed. I did it that way :

```
public static void Update<T>(Expression<Action<T>> action) where T : class
```

Inside the Update method, the expression is analyzed with a standard Visitor pattern : i am able to get the properties assigned, and the values associated.

The method is called like this :

```
Update<Employee>(o => new Employee() { FirstName = "Mike", Email = "mike@so.com" });
```

Thanks again for your help !

Mike

Comment: Are you aware that this is a very strange API? `Update` requires an `Action<Employee>`, i.e. a method that takes an `Employee` and returns `void`. But the expression you pass doesn't use the `Employee` that is passed in. And because the return type of an `Action` is `void`, it is also impossible to use the newly created object. Maybe it would be better to use a `Func<Employee>` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot analyze delegates. To analyze, you would need an expression tree:

```
public static void Update(Expression<Action<Employee>> action)
```

Unfortunately, lambda expressions with bodies can't automatically be converted to expression trees by the compiler<strike>, so you will need to constrain the expression to one property per call.</strike>
Additionally, expression trees with assignment operators can't be converted automatically either, so you will have to find some other way.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this code raises the error "An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator", even with only one property call : Update<Employee>(o => o.LastName= "lastname");

Comment: @user2530841: Indeed, you are correct. I wasn't really aware of that.